# Warning: Creating default object from empty value - Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am getting an warning message in my website :

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /homepages/16/d381040813/htdocs/components/com_events_booking/models/event.php on line 169
```

I have opened 169 th line in event.php , the code is:

```
$row->event->BeforeDisplay = trim(implode("\n", $results));
```

My event.php file is :

```
  <?php

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.application.component.model');

/**
 * Event_Booking Component - Event Model
 * @package     Event_Booking
 * @subpackage  Model
 */
class Events_BookingModelEvent extends JModel {
    /** @var int Total of documents */
    var $_total             = null;
    /** @var object Pagination object */
    var $_pagination        = null;
    /** @var string */
    var $nullDate           = null;
    /** @var string */
    var $now                = null;
    /** @var int */
    var $_id                = null;
    /** @var array realty data */
    var $_data              = null;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    function __construct() {
        global $mainframe, $option;
        parent::__construct();

        $this->nullDate = $this->_db->getNullDate();
        $jdate          = JFactory::getDate();
        $this->now      = $jdate->toMySQL();

        $id = JRequest::getInt('id', 0);
        if( !$id ){
            $session    = &JFactory::getSession();
            $user       = JFactory::getUser();
            $joinevent  = $session->get('joinevent');
            if( @count( $joinevent[$user->get('id')] ) ){
                $id = $joinevent[$user->get('id')]['id'];       
            }
        }
        $this->setId($id);
    }

    /**
     * Method to set the identifier
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   int $id realty identifier
     */
    function setId($id) {
        $this->_id      = $id;
        $this->_data    = null;
    }

    /**
     * Method to get event item data.
     * @access  public
     * @return  object
     */
    function getData($id = null) {
        // Lets load the data if it doesn't already exist
        if (empty($this->_data)) {
            $id     = $id ? $id : $this->_id;
            $query  = 'SELECT a.*, b.id AS bid , b.title AS btitle , c.id AS cid , c.title AS ctitle, c.street, c.city, c.state, c.zip, ct.name AS `country`, c.website, c.latitude, c.longitude'
                . ' FROM #__events_events AS a'
                . ' INNER JOIN #__events_categories AS b ON a.category_id = b.id'
                . ' INNER JOIN #__events_venues AS c ON a.venue_id = c.id'
                . ' LEFT JOIN #__events_countries AS ct ON ct.code LIKE c.country'
                . ' WHERE a.published = 1 AND a.id = '. (int) $id
                ;
            $this->_db->setQuery($query);
            $this->_data    = $this->_db->loadObject();
        }

        if (!$this->_data->id) {
            JError::raiseError( 404, JText::_('COM_EVENTS_BOOKING_EVENT_NOT_FOUND'));
        }

        return $this->_data;
    }
    /**
     * Method to get group item data.
     * @access  public
     * @return  array
     */
    function getGroup($id = null) {
        $query  = 'SELECT g.* FROM #__events_groups as g'
                . ' WHERE g.published = 1 AND a.id = '. (int) $id
                ;
        $this->_db->setQuery($query);
        $row    = $this->_db->loadObject();
        return $row;
    }

    /**
     * Method to get Expired item data.
     * @access  public
     * @return  array
     */
    function getExpired() {
        $date   = new JDate();
        $id     = $this->_id;
        $query  = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #__events_events AS a WHERE a.id = '.(int)$id.' AND a.published = 1 AND a.expired > '.$this->_db->Quote($date->toMySQL());
        $this->_db->setQuery($query);
        $row = $this->_db->loadResult();
        return $row;
    }

    /**
     * Method to get Expired Capacity.
     * @access  public
     * @return  array
     */
    function getCapacity() {
        $data   = $this->getData();
        $id     = $this->_id;
        $result = $this->getMemberCapacity($data->capacity);
        return $result;
    }
    /**
     * Method to get Member Capacity COM_EVENTS_BOOKING_JOIN_EVENT.
     * @access  public
     * @return  array
     */
    function getMemberCapacity($capacity=0) {
        $id     = $this->_id;
//      $query  = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #__events_members AS a WHERE a.event_id = '.(int)$id;
        $query  = 'SELECT COUNT(*)'
                . ' FROM #__events_members AS a'
                . ' INNER JOIN #__events_bookings AS b ON b.id = a.booking_id'
                . ' WHERE a.event_id = '.(int)$id
                . ' AND b.approved = 1'
                . ' AND a.approved = 1'
                ;

        $this->_db->setQuery($query);
        $row    = $this->_db->loadResult();
        $result = array();
        $result['m_capacity'] = $row;
        $result['e_capacity'] = (int)($capacity-(int)$row);
        return $result;
    }


    function execPlugins(&$row, $view, $task){
        $params     = &JComponentHelper::getParams('com_events_booking');
        $limitstart = JRequest::getInt('limitstart');
        //Import plugins
        $dispatcher = &JDispatcher::getInstance();
        JPluginHelper::importPlugin ('content');

        $row->text = $row->description;

        $results = $dispatcher->trigger('onBeforeDisplay', array ( 'com_events_booking.event', &$row, &$params, $limitstart));
        $row->event->BeforeDisplay = trim(implode("\n", $results));

        $results = $dispatcher->trigger('onAfterDisplay', array ( 'com_events_booking.event', &$row, &$params, $limitstart));
        $row->event->AfterDisplay = trim(implode("\n", $results));

        $results = $dispatcher->trigger('onAfterDisplayTitle', array ( 'com_events_booking.event', &$row, &$params, $limitstart));
        $row->event->AfterDisplayTitle = trim(implode("\n", $results));

        $results = $dispatcher->trigger('onBeforeDisplayContent', array ( 'com_events_booking.event', &$row, &$params, $limitstart));
        $row->event->BeforeDisplayContent = trim(implode("\n", $results));

        $results = $dispatcher->trigger('onAfterDisplayContent', array ( 'com_events_booking.event', &$row, &$params, $limitstart));
        $row->event->AfterDisplayContent = trim(implode("\n", $results));

        $dispatcher->trigger('onContentPrepare', array ( 'com_events_booking.event', &$row, &$params, $limitstart));
        return $row;
    }

    /**
     * Method to store the booking
     *
     * @access public
     * @param $data
     * @return boolean True on success
     */
    function store($data) {
        //$row = JTable::getInstance('form', 'Table');
        $row =& $this->getTable('event');

        // bind the form fields to the version table
        if (!$row->bind($data)) {
            $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());

            return false;
        }

        // make sure the category is valid
        if (!$row->check()) {
            $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());
            return false;
        }

        // store the category table to the database
        if (!$row->store()) {
            $this->setError($this->_db->getErrorMsg());

            return false;
        }
        return $row;
    }
```

I googled a day, but no result. Please help me to hide this warning or solving this.

the page url in which error shown:
http://www.lefoodist.biz/calendar-gb/calendar-hosted-gastronomic-dinners?view=event&id=478#box-details

Comment: you can hide errors with error_reporting(E_NONE) or setting proper value in php.ini or with function ini_set() you can also use @ operator to hide error. The error may be cause also by previous line so you should include this line to your post as well

Comment: yes i have used it and now got result @robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere have you created a `$row->event` object.  So when you set `$row->event->BeforeDisplay`, the BeforeDisplay object is being created against something that hasn't been set.  If you do something like `$row->event = new stdClass();` before your events start to run, this should clear it up.